# Fail aunthentication in DAS using single sign on by middle of Identity Server of WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-das, wso2-identity-server

I am using Data Analytics Server (DAS) and Identity Server (IS) of wso2. I want login in DAS and other products of wso2 in the future with the single sign on (SSO) in the Identity Server. I follow this instructions https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Enabling+SSO+for+WSO2+Servers. When I try to login in DAS, the system redirect me to authentication windows in IS, but after write correctly user and password, the system send me to DAS, but with this result (view image)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution Steps:

1. Go to WSO2 IS, in the "Service Providers" configuration and **uncheck** the 
   "**Enable Assertion Encryption**" option.
2. Go to WSO2 IS, in the "Service Provider" configuration and **select** in "Certificate Alias" the **wso2carbon** value, not wso2carbon.cert.
3. In WSO2 DAS 3.0.0, go to the **authenticators**.xml file, and **uncommented** the line with **IdPCertAlias** parameter value "**wso2carbon**"

Restart the server an try again.!!!!